# Apple Id Signin Authorization in Simulators

Tags: debugging, authorization, ios-simulator, solution, apple-id

I have my project running with xcode12, I am working on integrating apple id signin in my project. I dont have a real device with connect and debug as my device is with iOS14.2 which is not compatible with xcode12 and also i cannot run my project with xcode12.2 as there is a framework dont have sdk for higher than swift5.3 compiler. My only option to test Apple id singin process in simulator. I have tried it with iPhone11 (14.0) simulator, on click the apple signin button, it is prompting to share / hide my email and asking to enter the passcode, when i give the passcode, i didn't get any response in the authorization completion method

```
 func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization)
```

but when i tap the outside the popup window, the delegate method

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) is called.
```

I get the below warning / error from apple sign in process

```
Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7003 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=com.myappname.domain}
Authorization Failed: Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1001 "(null)"
```

As i dont have an option to debug the scenario by connecting to the real device as i dont have device with ios14 and i need to debug and test using simulator only. Kindly guide me how to debug and resolve this issue.

Thanks,
V Muralidharan

Comment: After a long struggle, got a way to debug the code with my mobile by disabling the framework with lower version, but when i print the appleid credentials in authorization process, i get (lldb) po appleIDCredential.fullName
▿ Optional<PersonNameComponents>
  - some : 

Printing description of *(authorization._credential.some._email):
(id) [0] = <parent is NULL>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your time.

After a long struggle, got a way to debug the code with my mobile by disabling the framework with lower version and debugged the code with real device. Got it worked.